# Bootstrap CSS Tile Grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I am repeating some kind of tiles in a div with class row. It looks like this:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="margin-bottom:15;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-6" style="width: auto;">
        <div style="position: relative;">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-6">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">HEADER</h:outputText>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">TEXT</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6"><button>stuff</button></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="margin-bottom:15;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-6" style="width: auto;">
          <div style="position: relative;">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-6">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">HEADER</h:outputText>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">TEXT</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6"><button>stuff</button></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="margin-bottom:15;">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-6" style="width: auto;">
            <div style="position: relative;">
              <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-6">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12">HEADER</h:outputText>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-12">TEXT</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6"><button>stuff</button></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
















      </div>
```

It should look like this: [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I0wd.jpg)
Which basically means that no matter what display size it should always show as many tiles as possible in one row. Currently this does not work on a mobile device for example. Anyone know to fix it?

Comment: did you try **col-xs-** ?

Comment: Yes I did but I am getting the problem, that the images are now overlapping

Comment: yes i think there is too much nested row and col in your example, i think you should make them less

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3" style="margin-bottom:15;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-6" style="width: auto;">
                <div style="position: relative;">
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">HEADER</h:outputText>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">TEXT</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6"><button>stuff</button></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ccol-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3" style="margin-bottom:15;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-6" style="width: auto;">
                <div style="position: relative;">
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">HEADER</h:outputText>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">TEXT</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6"><button>stuff</button></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3" style="margin-bottom:15;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-6" style="width: auto;">
                <div style="position: relative;">
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">HEADER</h:outputText>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">TEXT</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6"><button>stuff</button></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```